# Approaching people beyond poverty

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-request, translation

Is "Approaching people **beyond** poverty" understandable?

Context: this is for a short caption in a trailer that presents a social study. The social experiment's goal is to meet people living in third world countries. Studies in such fields face many difficulties (language, customs, differences...). One of them is poverty rush conditions (for instance hygiene conditions: there is a huge life style gap between western life style and traditional one...).

What I mean by "Approaching people **beyond** poverty" is that the protocol required the experimenters to live like and with the same conditions  the locals. "Beyond poverty" means to overcome this difficulty.

In french this construction works : Approcher les hommes **au delà de** la pauvreté et des différences. The literal translation is approaching people **beyond** poverty and differences

Answer (score 1):

Beyond gives me the idea that these people are *more than* poor.

How about

> Approaching people **across** the poverty barrier / boundary.

I don't see any negative connotations there, but that doesn't mean there are none, of course...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't realized it could also be understood that way! The problem with barrier is that it emphasizes too much the difficulty. Barrier is a limitation and poverty is not a limitation.  For instance, if I use "despite" it will create the same problem: a strict limitation.
Would it makes more sens if I use punctuation like "Approaching people, beyond poverty" or "Approaching, beyond poverty, the people"?

Comment: How about boundary? Beyond poverty keeps, also with the comma, having the idea of "more than" rather than "across" for me.

Comment: Boundary sounds better but still keeps this limitation idea (way less that barrier however). In the same time, I understand that "across" is better and more precise than "beyond" so I will definitively go with "across". Thanks so much for your help Oerkelens!

Comment: *approaching people beyond poverty* also means to me that someone is approaching the poor to solve their problems more than just solving their poverty. Every client is like a family member of mine. To me, business is *beyond* monetary gains.

Comment: I agree with Maulik that though being ambiguous, I would interpret the phrase the way Maulik did. About the phrase, I'm not familiar with this usage of *approaching people*. However, I think *Approaching people's beyond poverty*, or even better, *Approaching people beyond their poverty*, could solve the ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for "their poverty", it does remove the ambiguity. I am not sure how to read "approaching people's beyond poverty" though. I cannot place the possessive there.

Comment: @MaulikV yes, _beyond monetary gains_ is not ambiguous. _Beyond_ can be replaced there with _more than_, which is exactly what creates the problem with the OP's case :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! I will then go with _beyond THEIR poverty_. Thanks Damkerng and Oerkelens!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with this.

1. *Beyond* in English implies a point or line (it may be physical or figurative) which is crossed. Consequently, *beyond poverty* means arriving in some sense at "poverty" and then going a step ***into something else***. Consider Nietzsche's *Jenseits von Gut und Böse*—this is generally translated *Beyond Good and Evil*, but Shaw rendered it more pointedly as *Through Good and Evil and Out the Other Side*. This is why oerkelens suggests *across the poverty boundary* or *barrier*.
2. English *approach* does not, I think, bear quite the direct and emotional sense which seems to be possible with French *s’approcher*; it is more tentative.

Perhaps *reaching across the poverty line* might suit your purpose? It suggests an effort to touch, to come in contact with others.

Comment: Thanks Stoney! I didn't know _Approach_ is more tentative in English than in french. However, (**to me**) _reaching_ sound more like _rejoindre_ in french (something like meet, rejoin) Then my phrase will sound like _being poor among the poor_ which is too pretentious. What I try to say by using _approach_ is : getting closer in order to share times with the people, to live like them but not to **be** like them (the experimenters are not poor, there are just living like and among the poor _for a definite amount of time_ ).

Comment: @Giim *Reach* covers a lot of territory. If you speak of "reaching across" something it means to extend a hand across X in order to grasp or touch Y. The same goal is also expressed by "reach out to Y". According to [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=reach), this sense seems to be most often translated by *atteindre*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @StoneyB, I didn't know "reach across" had this meaning. This is so useful, thanks again!